# how to verify whether latest python version installed properly

Tags: python-3.x

when I try to check python version in Centos7 by typing  command

1) python --version
**-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.6: No such file or directory**
                 OR
2) which python

**"alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.6'.**

Could anyone explain me why it shows like this instead of showing python version?

Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you just run `python`?

Comment: @kakigadol thank you. When I type python it shows Python 2.7.5. Actually i tried to update the version to 3.6. Today i figured out the problem was in path location. Now location "alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.6'' changed  to alias python='/usr/bin/python3.6'  in ~/.bashrc file. Now it works fine and shows default updated python version Python as 3.6.8. Thank you Kaki gadol for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to sum up, for future people who will look in this question:
when installing different versions of python on linux using package manager (in this case yum because you are using CentOS, but it might be apt or something else)  linux installs the *side-by-side*, meaning you have all of the versions installed together.

If you want to use a specific version other than your linux distribution diffault one you need to call it explicitly (i.e. python3.6 or python3.8)
Make sure you are looking for the wanted python version on the right path.

When you want to run some version of python after installing it I suggest you to just write `python` in the bash and just hit `tab+tab` and the bash will suggest all the installed versions in the `$PATH`.